# JSON.deserializeUntyped problems with long list

Tags: apex, json, list, map, deserialize

I have this string s1 :

```
{"iss":"backend","nbf":499071708,"iat":1499071708,"exp":2499071708,"Server":{"Version":"1.0","Identity":"backend"},"Data":{"ContentList":["AzEuMFveOpUnBpFTJ5yYdqdZxJs=","AzEuMCTwj+JAzuZXsYDqiJ/od5Y=","AzEuMO8qfFMY5Q2H8ooj3bhUBB8=","AzEuMCUDXAbCjom1OQI+DzaFJnw=","AzEuMG97HAvirlTWsUCQUcXYge8=","AzEuMOIWd2Wq8hjdckeZr7wiiyA=","AzEuMEnR2z8WixFoPLbqonDNw+c=","AzEuMCB5BdoE/jXg1PyM9nCzqMA=","AzEuMF/bqXDosIqrsclbXOTtGi0=","AzEuMB3w9Kr8DCuIvbUVETS3d2I=","AzEuMMJ4nby5baP354yZdtPBZSk=","AzEuMOreiPhBQb9/zwrkT9swPnk="],"KeyId":"RV1XNapXLxELLUquNGFLdj1uFSRa3/GmgeCePj7DcUg=","CheckSum":"47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU="},"ResponseCode":"SUCCESS","Date":"2017-07-03T08:48:28.142Z"}
```

And I am using this function (Map < String,Object >)JSON.deserializeUntyped(s1);

In the Content List there are 12 words but when I deserialize all the string I am receiving in the Content List only 10 word and three points (...)

It is the deserialized string s1

```
 {Data={CheckSum=47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=, ContentList=(AzEuMFveOpUnBpFTJ5yYdqdZxJs=, AzEuMCTwj+JAzuZXsYDqiJ/od5Y=, AzEuMO8qfFMY5Q2H8ooj3bhUBB8=, AzEuMCUDXAbCjom1OQI+DzaFJnw=, AzEuMG97HAvirlTWsUCQUcXYge8=, AzEuMOIWd2Wq8hjdckeZr7wiiyA=, AzEuMEnR2z8WixFoPLbqonDNw+c=, AzEuMCB5BdoE/jXg1PyM9nCzqMA=, AzEuMF/bqXDosIqrsclbXOTtGi0=, AzEuMB3w9Kr8DCuIvbUVETS3d2I=, ...), KeyId=RV1XNapXLxELLUquNGFLdj1uFSRa3/GmgeCePj7DcUg=}, Date=2017-07-03T08:48:28.142Z, ResponseCode=SUCCESS, Server={Identity=backend, Version=1.0}, exp=2499071708, iat=1499071708, iss=backend, nbf=499071708}
```

It is the problem :

[image]

Can you help me ? , I don't understand why I am losing words from the Content List which is in the Data of the string

Here you can see the object that I would like to receive :

[image]

And here you can see the object that I received :

[image]

Thank you

Comment: do you have that dots in debug log if so, that is normal behavior, as debug log shows not whole, but only few elements of collection, and for rest of them dots are printed?  did you try to save it to any text field, that have enough length to store content ?

Comment: It is not only in the debug log ,  like you can see there is enougth space in the debug log because it is printing the others parts of the string , I am losing data only from the Conten List which is in the Data of the String `, AzEuMB3w9Kr8DCuIvbUVETS3d2I=, ...), KeyId=RV`

Comment: It's the debug logs doing that; you'd want to iterate over the list and debug all the values to prove to yourself that they are there.

Comment: ... with the debug logs doing that so a massive collection doesn't consume a lot of log space; you just get the first 10 (?) items. To see all the data `JSON.serializePretty` the map.

Comment: no it is not the debug, to prove it, I have selected the Content List Of the Data and I added a test word to check what you said and its printed the word test;  Here you can see the string which is the Content List of the Data from the precedent string:     (AzEuMO0HwK0qCGOEhYUZ0pV3+6k=, AzEuMEM/+qE8XALHY5Fb+XASc0U=, AzEuMKGdG3DfKNhiM0k1AbtVhLw=, AzEuMAyARHr5+cQxNC2LkyC0RI8=, AzEuMIleJEKIbZGLGnD32i+2Gnc=, AzEuMKjXfSwzjGuAHR14NHKQ7cM=, AzEuMIWM1Eg7StxlYHeLsWGlUns=, AzEuMOME93cFukiY02qnF63theA=, AzEuMC/c6FYI/yXk+pHB2iK1jno=, AzEuMJwfVdZmcOPQ3AMi2BJofsw=, ...)test

Comment: and @ Keith C , I don't want to serialize my string , I would like to deserialize it , to get the fields of the object , First I get the Data , and then I get the Content List so its should to be an object Map<String,Object> , the problem is that my Content list is incomplete , it is not the debug...

Comment: @Raphym - I think you are missing the point of what you are being told. If your only source is the debug logs and you see 3 elipse ... then it is simply the debug log truncating the collection value (not the entire string). If you would try what has been suggested instead of "not wanting to do that" you will see the value is fully there. You can remove the loop/serialization after you see what they mean. If you are seeing the ... outside of the debug log please clarify. Your addition of test is invalid as it is outside of the collection that was truncated and thus why you see it.

Comment: Raphym understod - I wrote "To see all the data `JSON.serializePretty` **the map**" meaning the result of the deserialization and purely to check the map content for the right number of list items.

Comment: @Eric ,  my **source** is not the debug logs , my service send a list of word to a web service , this web service return me a list of encrypted words and then I update the records values of the object.  The problem is that after 10 it doesn't work , the value of the 11 word is ... and the word 12 did not appear. I printed the crypted list of the json webservice all is OK , the problem is hapening only after this function , and YES it is not the debug mode only that I check , I can see in the record detail page that the word 11 is ... and not the true value that I receive from the webservice

Comment: If you are receiving data like that the the problem is on the end sending the data.

Comment: @Eric What do you mean "is on the end sending the data" , the json that I received from the webservice is fine , It is working for 10 words , so why it would not be working for a list of 12 words ... The list "Content List" which is in the "Data" is not the end of the json like you can see in the picture of the question , the end is Response Code and after there is the Date. So I think that the problem is in the function "JSON.deserializeUntyped". This function cut a part of my json in the middle (This part is my list "Content List")

Comment: @Eric When I use an online web site to deserialize my json , all is ok  ,like you can see in the picture, the only problem is that I don't understand  Why this function does'nt work correctly ? .  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having a hard time following where you are seeing what. But I believe what you are seeing is in the debug logs the string being abbreviated.

You will be better served to create a class to deserialize into which can be easily generated by JSON2APEX and the class I generated is below:

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//

public class JSON2Apex {

    public class JSON2Apex {
        public String iss;
        public Integer nbf;
        public Integer iat;
        public Long exp;
        public Server Server;
        public Data Data;
        public String ResponseCode;
        public String Date;
    }

    public class Server {
        public String Version;
        public String Identity;
    }

    public class Data {
        public List<String> ContentList;
        public String KeyId;
        public String CheckSum;
    }

    
    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

Simply use the following code to deserialize:

```
JSON2Apex obj = JSON2APEX.parse([YOURSTRINGHERE]);
```

This will get you a nice object.

Now, back to your original way.

Your Key Data contains an object itself and thus when output in the debug logs directly will display the behavior you stated.

```
String t = '{"iss":"backend","nbf":499071708,"iat":1499071708,"exp":2499071708,"Server":{"Version":"1.0","Identity":"backend"},"Data":{"ContentList":["AzEuMFveOpUnBpFTJ5yYdqdZxJs=","AzEuMCTwj+JAzuZXsYDqiJ/od5Y=","AzEuMO8qfFMY5Q2H8ooj3bhUBB8=","AzEuMCUDXAbCjom1OQI+DzaFJnw=","AzEuMG97HAvirlTWsUCQUcXYge8=","AzEuMOIWd2Wq8hjdckeZr7wiiyA=","AzEuMEnR2z8WixFoPLbqonDNw+c=","AzEuMCB5BdoE/jXg1PyM9nCzqMA=","AzEuMF/bqXDosIqrsclbXOTtGi0=","AzEuMB3w9Kr8DCuIvbUVETS3d2I=","AzEuMMJ4nby5baP354yZdtPBZSk=","AzEuMOreiPhBQb9/zwrkT9swPnk="],"KeyId":"RV1XNapXLxELLUquNGFLdj1uFSRa3/GmgeCePj7DcUg=","CheckSum":"47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU="},"ResponseCode":"SUCCESS","Date":"2017-07-03T08:48:28.142Z"}';
Map<String,Object> tmp = (Map<String,Object>)json.deserializeUntyped(t);

System.debug(tmp.get('Data'));
```

> 07:19:47.26 (28506570)|USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|{CheckSum=47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=, ContentList=(AzEuMFveOpUnBpFTJ5yYdqdZxJs=, AzEuMCTwj+JAzuZXsYDqiJ/od5Y=, AzEuMO8qfFMY5Q2H8ooj3bhUBB8=, AzEuMCUDXAbCjom1OQI+DzaFJnw=, AzEuMG97HAvirlTWsUCQUcXYge8=, AzEuMOIWd2Wq8hjdckeZr7wiiyA=, AzEuMEnR2z8WixFoPLbqonDNw+c=, AzEuMCB5BdoE/jXg1PyM9nCzqMA=, AzEuMF/bqXDosIqrsclbXOTtGi0=, AzEuMB3w9Kr8DCuIvbUVETS3d2I=, ...), KeyId=RV1XNapXLxELLUquNGFLdj1uFSRa3/GmgeCePj7DcUg=}

The following code however shows how to deserialize it and debug all the value proving that the `...` that you were seeing is a function of the abbreviation. Why you are seeing it actually stored in your SF Object I cannot answer without seeing your code.

The follow shows the output as you would expect with all values (crude but works):

```
String t = '{"iss":"backend","nbf":499071708,"iat":1499071708,"exp":2499071708,"Server":{"Version":"1.0","Identity":"backend"},"Data":{"ContentList":["AzEuMFveOpUnBpFTJ5yYdqdZxJs=","AzEuMCTwj+JAzuZXsYDqiJ/od5Y=","AzEuMO8qfFMY5Q2H8ooj3bhUBB8=","AzEuMCUDXAbCjom1OQI+DzaFJnw=","AzEuMG97HAvirlTWsUCQUcXYge8=","AzEuMOIWd2Wq8hjdckeZr7wiiyA=","AzEuMEnR2z8WixFoPLbqonDNw+c=","AzEuMCB5BdoE/jXg1PyM9nCzqMA=","AzEuMF/bqXDosIqrsclbXOTtGi0=","AzEuMB3w9Kr8DCuIvbUVETS3d2I=","AzEuMMJ4nby5baP354yZdtPBZSk=","AzEuMOreiPhBQb9/zwrkT9swPnk="],"KeyId":"RV1XNapXLxELLUquNGFLdj1uFSRa3/GmgeCePj7DcUg=","CheckSum":"47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU="},"ResponseCode":"SUCCESS","Date":"2017-07-03T08:48:28.142Z"}';
Map<String,Object> tmp = (Map<String,Object>)json.deserializeUntyped(t);

for(String key : tmp.keySet()){
    if(key != 'Data') {
        System.debug('Key: ' + key + ' - Value: ' + tmp.get(key));
    }else{
        String dataString = json.serialize(tmp.get(key));
        Map<String,Object> dataValues = (Map<String,Object>)json.deserializeUntyped(dataString);
        for(String dataKey : dataValues.keySet()){
            if(dataKey == 'ContentList'){
                object[] cl = (object[])dataValues.get(dataKey);
                for(object listItem : cl){
                    System.debug('Content List Item: ' + listItem);
                }
            }else {
                System.debug('Data Key: ' + dataKey + ' - Data Value: ' + dataValues.get(dataKey));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

> 07:13:19.21 (22738131)|USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|Key: iss - Value: backend
>
> 07:13:19.21 (22911886)|USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|Key: nbf - Value: 499071708
>
> 07:13:19.21 (23068383)|USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|Key: iat - Value: 14990717080
>
> 07:13:19.21 (23174679)|USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|Key: exp - Value: 2499071708
>
> 07:13:19.21 (23282582)|USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|Key: Server - Value: {Identity=backend, Version=1.0}
>
> 07:13:19.21 (24385363)|USER_DEBUG|[24]|DEBUG|Data Key: CheckSum - Data Value: 47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=
>
> 07:13:19.21 (24497528)|USER_DEBUG|[24]|DEBUG|Data Key: KeyId - Data Value: RV1XNapXLxELLUquNGFLdj1uFSRa3/GmgeCePj7DcUg=
>
> 07:13:19.21 (24725499)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Content List Item: AzEuMFveOpUnBpFTJ5yYdqdZxJs=
>
> 07:13:19.21 (24807108)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Content List Item: AzEuMCTwj+JAzuZXsYDqiJ/od5Y=
>
> 07:13:19.21 (24883908)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Content List Item: AzEuMO8qfFMY5Q2H8ooj3bhUBB8=
>
> 07:13:19.21 (24959225)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Content List Item: AzEuMCUDXAbCjom1OQI+DzaFJnw=
>
> 07:13:19.21 (25034162)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Content List Item: AzEuMG97HAvirlTWsUCQUcXYge8=
>
> 07:13:19.21 (25107635)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Content List Item: AzEuMOIWd2Wq8hjdckeZr7wiiyA=
>
> 07:13:19.21 (25180741)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Content List Item: AzEuMEnR2z8WixFoPLbqonDNw+c=
>
> 07:13:19.21 (25253642)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Content List Item: AzEuMCB5BdoE/jXg1PyM9nCzqMA=
>
> 07:13:19.21 (25327031)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Content List Item: AzEuMF/bqXDosIqrsclbXOTtGi0=
>
> 07:13:19.21 (25404523)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Content List Item: AzEuMB3w9Kr8DCuIvbUVETS3d2I=
>
> 07:13:19.21 (25483266)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Content List Item: AzEuMMJ4nby5baP354yZdtPBZSk=
>
> 07:13:19.21 (25561852)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Content List Item: AzEuMOreiPhBQb9/zwrkT9swPnk=
>
> 07:13:19.21 (25699372)|USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|Key: ResponseCode - Value: SUCCESS
>
> 07:13:19.21 (25792186)|USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|Key: Date - Value: 2017-07-03T08:48:28.142Z